# eliminate gap between Jpanel in borderLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, border-layout

I am adding a 2 jpanel (CENTER AND PAGE_END) to another Jpanel that goes in a JFrame. There is a HUGE gap between the 2 panels (panneauDateDebut and panneauDateFin) that I would like to eliminate. I have tried to set them in different configurations (start/center, start/end, center/end) but without luck. How can this be done ?

edit to have a working code

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class CreerModificationAbsence extends JDialog {

    private JPanel modificationAbsence1, modificationAbsence2,
            modificationAbsence3, panneauDateDebut, panneauDateFin;
    private JButton modifier, annuler;
    private JLabel raison, prenomNomEmpl, prenomNomChef;
    private JComboBox<String> raisonC, heureDebutC, heureFinC, minuteDebutC,
            minuteFinC;
    private JTextField prenomNomEmplT, prenomnomChefT;
    private final String[] raisonAbsence = { "Malade" };

    private JLabel dateDebut, dateFin;
    private JTextField dateDebutT, dateFinT;

    private final String[] heures = { "00" };
    private final String[] minutes = { "00", "15", "30", "45" };

    private BorderLayout gestionnaireComposant;
    private GridLayout gridGestionnaireComposant;
    private FlowLayout panneauMilieuLayout;
    final FlowLayout gestionnaireComposantBas;

    public CreerModificationAbsence() {
        super((Frame) null, "Modification - Absence d'employé", true);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 250));
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocation(400, 200);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        gestionnaireComposant = new BorderLayout();
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(gestionnaireComposant);

        // Modification Panneau Haut

        modificationAbsence1 = new JPanel();

        gridGestionnaireComposant = new GridLayout(3, 2, 2, 2);
        modificationAbsence1.setLayout(gridGestionnaireComposant);

        raison = new JLabel("Raison : ");
        raisonC = new JComboBox<>(raisonAbsence);
        raisonC.setEditable(true);
        prenomNomEmpl = new JLabel("Prénom et Nom de l'employé : ");
        prenomNomEmplT = new JTextField();
        prenomNomChef = new JLabel("Prénom et Nom du chef d'équipe : ");
        prenomnomChefT = new JTextField();

        modificationAbsence1.add(raison);
        modificationAbsence1.add(raisonC);
        modificationAbsence1.add(prenomNomEmpl);
        modificationAbsence1.add(prenomNomEmplT);
        modificationAbsence1.add(prenomNomChef);
        modificationAbsence1.add(prenomnomChefT);

        // Modification Panneau Milieu

        modificationAbsence2 = new JPanel();
        panneauDateDebut = new JPanel();
        panneauDateFin = new JPanel();

        panneauMilieuLayout = new FlowLayout();

        panneauDateDebut.setLayout(panneauMilieuLayout);
        panneauDateDebut.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 0));
                   panneauDateDebut.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);

        panneauDateFin.setLayout(panneauMilieuLayout);
        panneauDateFin.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        panneauDateFin.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 113));

        modificationAbsence2.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0,0));

        dateDebutT = new JTextField(12);
        heureDebutC = new JComboBox<>(heures);
        minuteDebutC = new JComboBox<>(minutes);
        dateFinT = new JTextField(12);
        heureFinC = new JComboBox<>(heures);
        minuteFinC = new JComboBox<>(minutes);

        dateDebut = new JLabel("Date de début :");
        dateFin = new JLabel("Date de fin :");

        dateDebutT.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 20));
        dateFinT.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 20));
        dateDebut.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 20));
        dateFin.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 20));
        heureDebutC.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130, 20));
        minuteDebutC.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130, 20));
        heureFinC.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130, 20));
        minuteFinC.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130, 20));

        panneauDateDebut.add(dateDebut);
        panneauDateDebut.add(dateDebutT);
        panneauDateDebut.add(heureDebutC);
        panneauDateDebut.add(minuteDebutC);
        panneauDateFin.add(dateFin);
        panneauDateFin.add(dateFinT);
        panneauDateFin.add(heureFinC);
        panneauDateFin.add(minuteFinC);
        modificationAbsence2.add(panneauDateDebut, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        modificationAbsence2.add(panneauDateFin, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        // Modification Panneau Bas

        modificationAbsence3 = new JPanel();
        gestionnaireComposantBas = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT);
        modificationAbsence3.setLayout(gestionnaireComposantBas);

        modifier = new JButton("Modifier");
        annuler = new JButton("Annuler");

        modificationAbsence3.add(modifier);
        modificationAbsence3.add(annuler);

        this.add(modificationAbsence1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(modificationAbsence2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(modificationAbsence3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        /*this.*/setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
            /*this.*/setVisible(true);
    }

 public static void main(String s[]) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            CreerModificationAbsence textf = new CreerModificationAbsence();
        }
    });
}


}
```

Comment: There is a HUGE gap between the 2 panel this code did not talking about placing parent JPanel to the JFrame, for better help soone post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), demonstrated a.m. issue, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: I'm sure that you can't see all JComponents :-), not true that you descibed, not an SSCCE, I'll add rest of

Comment: can you please to create image in Paint, how it should looks like

Comment: Sorry, I have forgot to mention that I had cheated a bit by playing with panneauDateFin.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 113));

Setting it to 113 made it get close to the other pannel above.

Comment: if you comment out 
panneauDateDebut.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 0));

and 

panneauDateFin.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 113))

you will see what it should NOT lok like :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well for starters (and for enders, don't know if this is english or not): don't call `setPreferredSize()`! This is what is causing all your problems. Stop using that (forever in your life ~ bad sense of humour, don't take it harsh) and you will solve all your problems.

Try this instead:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CreerModificationAbsence extends JDialog {

    private JPanel modificationAbsence1, modificationAbsence2, modificationAbsence3, panneauDateDebut, panneauDateFin;
    private JButton modifier, annuler;
    private JLabel raison, prenomNomEmpl, prenomNomChef;
    private JComboBox<String> raisonC, heureDebutC, heureFinC, minuteDebutC, minuteFinC;
    private JTextField prenomNomEmplT, prenomnomChefT;
    private final String[] raisonAbsence = { "Malade" };

    private JLabel dateDebut, dateFin;
    private JTextField dateDebutT, dateFinT;

    private final String[] heures = { "00" };
    private final String[] minutes = { "00", "15", "30", "45" };

    private BorderLayout gestionnaireComposant;
    private GridLayout gridGestionnaireComposant;
    private FlowLayout panneauMilieuLayout;
    final FlowLayout gestionnaireComposantBas;

    public CreerModificationAbsence() {
        super((Frame) null, "Modification - Absence d'employé", true);

        // setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 250));
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        gestionnaireComposant = new BorderLayout();
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(gestionnaireComposant);

        // Modification Panneau Haut

        modificationAbsence1 = new JPanel();

        gridGestionnaireComposant = new GridLayout(3, 2, 2, 2);
        modificationAbsence1.setLayout(gridGestionnaireComposant);

        raison = new JLabel("Raison : ");
        raisonC = new JComboBox(raisonAbsence);
        raisonC.setEditable(true);
        prenomNomEmpl = new JLabel("Prénom et Nom de l'employé : ");
        prenomNomEmplT = new JTextField();
        prenomNomChef = new JLabel("Prénom et Nom du chef d'équipe : ");
        prenomnomChefT = new JTextField();

        modificationAbsence1.add(raison);
        modificationAbsence1.add(raisonC);
        modificationAbsence1.add(prenomNomEmpl);
        modificationAbsence1.add(prenomNomEmplT);
        modificationAbsence1.add(prenomNomChef);
        modificationAbsence1.add(prenomnomChefT);

        // Modification Panneau Milieu

        modificationAbsence2 = new JPanel();
        panneauDateDebut = new JPanel();
        panneauDateFin = new JPanel();

        panneauMilieuLayout = new FlowLayout();

        panneauDateDebut.setLayout(panneauMilieuLayout);
        panneauDateDebut.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);

        panneauDateFin.setLayout(panneauMilieuLayout);
        panneauDateFin.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);

        dateDebutT = new JTextField(12);
        heureDebutC = new JComboBox(heures);
        minuteDebutC = new JComboBox(minutes);
        dateFinT = new JTextField(12);
        heureFinC = new JComboBox(heures);
        minuteFinC = new JComboBox(minutes);

        dateDebut = new JLabel("Date de début :");
        dateFin = new JLabel("Date de fin :");

        panneauDateDebut.add(dateDebut);
        panneauDateDebut.add(dateDebutT);
        panneauDateDebut.add(heureDebutC);
        panneauDateDebut.add(minuteDebutC);
        panneauDateFin.add(dateFin);
        panneauDateFin.add(dateFinT);
        panneauDateFin.add(heureFinC);
        panneauDateFin.add(minuteFinC);
        modificationAbsence2.add(panneauDateDebut, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        modificationAbsence2.add(panneauDateFin, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        // Modification Panneau Bas

        modificationAbsence3 = new JPanel();
        gestionnaireComposantBas = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT);
        modificationAbsence3.setLayout(gestionnaireComposantBas);

        modifier = new JButton("Modifier");
        annuler = new JButton("Annuler");

        modificationAbsence3.add(modifier);
        modificationAbsence3.add(annuler);

        this.add(modificationAbsence1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(modificationAbsence2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(modificationAbsence3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        /*this.*/setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        /*this.*/setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                CreerModificationAbsence textf = new CreerModificationAbsence();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to the punch!  Posted anyways because I was almost done.

Comment: Wow, this helps alot only one thing, if I remove 

  dateDebutT.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 20));
  dateFinT.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 20));
  dateDebut.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 20));
  dateFin.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 20));
  heureDebutC.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130, 20));
  minuteDebutC.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130, 20));
  heureFinC.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130, 20));
  minuteFinC.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130, 20));

then my buttons are not the good size, how can I have them take those dimension other then setPreferredSize ?

Comment: @Mobidoy no problem. What do you mean, they don't have the good size? What size would you expect them to be? If you want them all to be the same size, I would recommend to wrap them in a `JPanel` with a `GridLayout` as ´LayoutManager`. Anyway, setting preferred size always leads to troubling results with undesired effects. Moreover, it is less maintainable (imagine tomorrow you decide to set the font of all your components to 24px, you have to modify the preferred size of everything) and does not work well with other L&F.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're experiencing is because you used `setPreferredSize` on the `JDialog`.  So what happens is that the Dialog is required to be the given size.  Because it now **has** to be that size, somethings got to give.  That's where the LayoutManagers take over.  In BorderLayout, whatever is in the Center will always stretch.

You can see what's happening if you set the background of your two panels you're having problems with:

```
    panneauDateDebut = new JPanel();
    panneauDateDebut.setOpaque(true);
    panneauDateDebut.setBackground(Color.blue);
    panneauDateFin = new JPanel();
    panneauDateFin.setOpaque(true);
    panneauDateFin.setBackground(Color.green);
```

The solution (that Guillaume pointed out as I'm writing) is to stop using the `setPreferredSize`.  So if your constructor looks like the following, you problem should be fixed:

```
public PageCentering() {
        super((Frame) null, "Modification - Absence d'employé", true);

        //setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 250));

        ...

}
```

Comment: Thanx Nick it realy does the work... Only resize my combo etc in that pannel too small now !

Comment: @Mobidoy Heh - that's why I like the BoxLayout best.  For my style, it gives me the most control over where the extra space goes (although it has quirks of it's own).  If you want something laid out from top to bottom just use `Box container = Box.createVerticalBox()` instead of `JPanel container = new JPanel`.  Then just add `container.add(Box.createVerticalGlue())` where you want the blank space.